# Does python has a functionality to upload tar.gz file from local pc to azure blob without extracting the files inside?

Tags: python, azure, blob, local, tar.gz

I have successfully downloaded tar.gz file from ftp server and have stored it in my local pc using below piece of code:

````
                data = BytesIO()
                save_file = ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, data.write, 1024)
                data.seek(0)
                uncompressed = gzip.decompress(data.read())
                    
                with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
                    file.write(uncompressed)
                    logging.info("success")

Now, I only want to upload the same to my azure blob storage without extracting it.
So far, I've tried this but it is letting me to do so:

```with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        blob.upload_blob(f, overwrite=True)``` 


what I am missing here?
````

Answer (score 0):

> to upload tar.gz file from local pc to azure blob

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

To upload tar.gz file from local folder to azure blob storage you can use below code.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient


blobservice=BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="<connect-string>")
blob_client = blobservice.get_blob_client(container="test",
                                                          blob="sample1.tar.gz")
# Upload the created file
with open("C:\\Users\\v-vsettu\\Downloads\\sample.tar.gz", "rb") as data:
    blob_client.upload_blob(data)
print("Uploaded!!!!!")
```

**Console:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Quickstart: Azure Blob Storage client library for Python - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python?tabs=connection-string%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli)